# Bounds of Chebyshev's function in an interval.

Tags: nt.number-theory

I want to know a good estimate for the upper bound of the following, $$\nu(x+y)-\nu(x)$$ where $\nu(x)=\sum_{p\leq x}\log p$. It would be of great help if anyone could give me some references.

Thanks.

Comment: For upper bounds, you are looking for the Brun Titchmarsh Theorem.  For lower bounds and asymptotics, see prime gaps: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Upper_bounds


Comment: For clarity, you might add that the sum is over primes p less than or equal to x.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.11.29

Comment: Also posted to m.se, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247289/on-bounds-of-chebyshevs-function-in-an-interval

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Eric Naslund's comment: Let $\pi(x)$ denote the number of primes less than $x$, then Montgomery & Vaughan proved that
$$ \pi(x+y)-\pi(x) \le 2 \pi(y)$$
for $x\ge 1$ and $y\ge 2.$

Comment: @Micah: I believe you need to have $y\geq 2$ so that the right hand side is nonzero.